# Improve this actor calling futures

Tags: scala, akka

I've an actor (Worker) which basically ask 3 other actors (Filter1, Filter2 and Filter3) for a result. If any of them return a false, It's unnecessary to wait for the others, like an "and" operation over the results. When a false response is receive, a cancel message is sent to the actors in a way to cancel the queued work and make it more effective in the execution.

Filters aren't children of Worker, but there are a common pool of actor which are used by all Worker actors. I use an Agent to maintain the collection of cancel Works. Then, before a particular work is processed, I check in the cancel agent if that work was cancel, and then avoid the execution for it. Cancel has a higher priority than Work, then, it is processed always first.

The code is something like this

Proxy, who create the actors tree:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import com.typesafe.config.Config

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorLogging
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.PoisonPill
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.agent.Agent
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRouter

class Proxy extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val agent1 = Agent(new HashSet[Work])
  val agent2 = Agent(new HashSet[Work])
  val agent3 = Agent(new HashSet[Work])

  val filter1 = context.actorOf(Props(Filter1(agent1)).withDispatcher("priorityMailBox-dispatcher")
    .withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(24)), "filter1")
  val filter2 = context.actorOf(Props(Filter2(agent2)).withDispatcher("priorityMailBox-dispatcher")
    .withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(24)), "filter2")
  val filter3 = context.actorOf(Props(Filter3(agent3)).withDispatcher("priorityMailBox-dispatcher")
    .withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(24)), "filter3")

  //val workerRouter = context.actorOf(Props[SerialWorker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(24)), name = "workerRouter")

  val workerRouter = context.actorOf(Props(new Worker(filter1, filter2, filter3)).withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(24)), name = "workerRouter")

  def receive = {
    case w: Work =>
      workerRouter forward w
  }

}
```

Worker:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorLogging
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.actorRef2Scala
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.pattern.pipe
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRouter
import akka.agent.Agent
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet

class Worker(filter1: ActorRef, filter2: ActorRef, filter3: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(30.seconds)

  def receive = {
    case w:Work =>

      val start = System.currentTimeMillis();

      val futureF3 = (filter3 ? w).mapTo[Response]
      val futureF2 = (filter2 ? w).mapTo[Response]
      val futureF1 = (filter1 ? w).mapTo[Response]

      val aggResult = Future.find(List(futureF3, futureF2, futureF1)) { res => !res.reponse }

      Await.result(aggResult, timeout.duration) match {
        case None =>
          Nqueen.fact(10500000L)
          log.info(s"[${w.message}] Procesado mensaje TRUE en ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ms");
          sender ! WorkResponse(w, true)

        case _ =>
          filter1 ! Cancel(w)
          filter2 ! Cancel(w)
          filter3 ! Cancel(w)
          log.info(s"[${w.message}] Procesado mensaje FALSE en ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ms");
          sender ! WorkResponse(w, false)
      }
  }
}
```

and Filters:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.util.Random

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorLogging
import akka.actor.actorRef2Scala
import akka.agent.Agent

trait CancellableFilter { this: Actor with ActorLogging =>

  //val canceledJobs = new HashSet[Int]
  val agent: Agent[HashSet[Work]]

  def cancelReceive: Receive = {
    case Cancel(w) =>
      agent.send(_ += w)
    //log.info(s"[$t] El trabajo se cancelara (si llega...)")
  }

  def cancelled(w: Work): Boolean =
    if (agent.get.contains(w)) {
      agent.send(_ -= w)
      true
    } else {
      false
    }

}

abstract class Filter extends Actor with ActorLogging { this: CancellableFilter =>

  val random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())

  def response: Boolean

  val timeToWait: Int

  val timeToExecutor: Long

  def receive = cancelReceive orElse {
    case w:Work if !cancelled(w) =>
      //log.info(s"[$t] Llego trabajo")
      Thread.sleep(timeToWait)
      Nqueen.fact(timeToExecutor)
      val r = Response(response)
      //log.info(s"[$t] Respondio ${r.reponse}")
      sender ! r
  }
}

object Filter1 {
  def apply(agente: Agent[HashSet[Work]]) = new Filter with CancellableFilter {
    val timeToWait = 74
    val timeToExecutor = 42000000L
    val agent = agente
    def response = true //random.nextBoolean
  }
}

object Filter2 {
  def apply(agente: Agent[HashSet[Work]]) = new Filter with CancellableFilter {
    val timeToWait = 47
    val timeToExecutor = 21000000L
    val agent = agente
    def response = true //random.nextBoolean
  }
}

object Filter3 {
  def apply(agente: Agent[HashSet[Work]]) = new Filter with CancellableFilter {
    val timeToWait = 47
    val timeToExecutor = 21000000L
    val agent = agente
    def response = true //random.nextBoolean
  }
}
```

Basically, I think Worker code is ugly and I want to make it better. Could you help to improve it?

Other point I want to improve is the cancel message. As I don't know which of the filters are done, I need to Cancel all of them, then, at least one cancel is redundant (Since this work is completed)

Comment: There's a few things that are concerning with your code.  First , what do you hope to achieve by sending a `Cancel` to the actors who are still doing work?  Once an `Actor` is processing a message, it will not pickup the next message until it's done with the current one.  That cancel will just sit in the mailbox of the actor until it finishes whatever long running task you hope to cancel at which point there is nothing to cancel.  Also, you should try to avoid `Thread.sleep` in an `Actor`.  Only bad will come of using that.  You should think of a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: One more thing.  Because you are using a router for the filters, when you send the cancel, there is no guarantee that the message will go to the actual instance behind the router that is performing the work you want to cancel anyway.

Comment: Thank you!. Filters has a priority inbox, where Work has a lower priority than cancel. Then filters pool are shared across all workers, I'm not sure that Work being to process before cancel. Then, If work haven't been processed, cancel is process first (Because of this priority). Yes, I've no possibility to process the work in the same Filter instance than the cancel. That's why I use an Agent to maintain the Cancel queue. This Agent is shared between Filters on the same type. Then Filter1(A) process the cancel and put its ID in the agent an Filter1(B) can see the cancel queue

Comment: This is an emulation of a real work. When I use Thread.sleep I'm trying to simulate an IO action (DB access in my case), and when I use NQueen.fact Y try to simulate a CPU work. Numbers passed as parameter to both of them aren't arbitrary. I've studied the behavior of the actual process and put a number according to the time I expect to spent in each action.

Answer (score 1):

It is minor, but why don't you store filters as sequence? `filters.foreach(f ! Cancel(w))` is nicer than

```
filter1 ! Cancel(w)
filter2 ! Cancel(w)
filter3 ! Cancel(w)
```

Same for other cases:

```
class Worker(filter1: ActorRef, filter2: ActorRef, filter3: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  private val filters = Seq(filter1, filter2, filter3)

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(30.seconds)

  def receive = {
    case w:Work =>

      val start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      val futures = filters.map { f =>
        (f ? w).mapTo[Response]
      }

      val aggResult = Future.find(futures) { res => !res.reponse }

      Await.result(aggResult, timeout.duration) match {
        case None =>
          Nqueen.fact(10500000L)
          log.info(s"[${w.message}] Procesado mensaje TRUE en ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ms");
          sender ! WorkResponse(w, true)

        case _ =>
          filters.foreach(f ! Cancel(w))
          log.info(s"[${w.message}] Procesado mensaje FALSE en ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} ms");
          sender ! WorkResponse(w, false)
      }
  }
```

You may also consider to write constructor as `Worker(filters: ActorRef*)` if you do not enforce exactly three filters. It think it is okay to sendoff one redundant cancel (alternatives I see is overly complicated). I'm not sure, but if filters will be created very fast, if may got randoms initialized with the same seed value.

Comment: Minor, but I like it so much! Thanks! My code looks better! Times are like the simulation done with Thead.sleep and Nqueen.fact. This are emulations of IO time and CPU time